# Keycloak Roles: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles') - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth, keycloak

I have the following code:

```
class Secured extends Component {

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { keycloak: null, authenticated: false, roles: [] };
}

componentDidMount() {
    const keycloak = Keycloak('/keycloak.json');
    keycloak.init({onLoad: 'login-required'}).then(authenticated => {
        this.setState({ keycloak: keycloak, authenticated: authenticated, roles: keycloak.tokenParsed.realm_access.roles})
    })
}

render() {
    if(this.state.keycloak) {
      if(this.state.authenticated)
      { if(this.state.roles.includes("prototype-user")){
        return ( //the rest of the code here
```

I always get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')` when the `keycloak.tokenParsed.realm_access.roles` does not have value. If it has value, the error does not appear.

I just started React.js last week and not quite familiar with JavaScript/TypeScript so I find it really hard to implement solutions I found with the same issue.

What is causing the error and how will I fix it?

Comment: Hey, do you always need the value to be there? if not you can use the conditional to  question mark prevent the code from failing when keycloak.tokenParsed.realm_access is undefined, what you have to do is keycloak?.tokenParsed?.realm_access?.roles

Comment: @usmahm this worked for me. I already found these question mark suggestion but do not really have any idea where to put. Thank you. I then added a condition for undefined array. It works perfectly now. Post this as an answer so I can accept

Comment: This is the line you need to edit in your case this.setState({ keycloak: keycloak, authenticated: authenticated, roles: keycloak?.tokenParsed?.realm_access?.roles})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent your code from failing when `keycloak.tokenParsed.realm_access` is undefined, you need to use a feature of javascript called optional chaining.

Here's how this works.

Let's say you have are trying to access an object property(or call on the object property) but you're not sure the object would always have that property for instance you can see that the code below doesn't have the `realm_access` as a property of the nested tokenParsed object and it fails when we try to access it.

```
const user = { 
  keycloak: null, 
  authenticated: false,
  tokenParsed: {
    token: '1245'
  }
}

const roles = user.tokenParsed.realm_access.roles //This would throw a TypeError
```

But say you want to prevent this error when the property is not there, that's where optional chaining comes in

```
const roles = user?.tokenParsed?.realm_access?.roles
```

By inserting a `?` between the property name and the period before the next property, it'll just return `undefined` instead of throwing an ugly error